# Bash script re-source a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i am just wondering is there anyway to source a file and then down in track source the file again?

I am using https://github.com/renatosilva/easyoptions on my bash script, i am sourcing easyoption.sh on the main script and which works fine. but when i have other scripts which gets loaded later on from the main script, i want easyoptions.sh to be sourced and --help should work on the last loaded file.

example:

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

## EasyOptions Sub Test
## Copyright (C) Someone
## Licensed under XYZ
##     -h, --help              All client scripts have this, it can be omitted.

script_dir=$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")
# source "${script_dir}/../easyoptions" || exit # Ruby implementation
source "${script_dir}/easyoptions.sh" || exit # Bash implementation, slower
```

main.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

## EasyOptions Main
## Copyright (C) Someone
## Licensed under XYZ
## Options:
##     -h, --help              All client scripts have this, it can be omitted.
##         --test      This loads test.sh.

script_dir=$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")
 # source "${script_dir}/../easyoptions" || exit # Ruby implementation
 source "${script_dir}/easyoptions.sh" || exit # Bash implementation, slower

if [[ -n "$test" ]];then
    source "${script_dir}/test.sh"
fi
```

Now when i try 
./main.sh --help
it displays

```
  EasyOptions Main
      Copyright (C) Someone
      Licensed under XYZ
      Options:
          -h, --help              All client scripts have this, it can be omitted.
>              --test      This loads test.sh.
```

Now i want below to work
./main.sh --test --help
and it should output

```
  EasyOptions Sub Test
      Copyright (C) Someone
      Licensed under XYZ
          -h, --help              All client scripts have this, it can be omitted.
```

But instead it always displays main.sh help

Answer (score 1):

In `main.sh` when you `source easyoptions.sh` it will parse all the command line options (including both `--help` and `--test`). Later when you `source test.sh` the *easyoptions* would have nothing to parse (i.e. it would not see `--help`). You can verify this by adding `echo "$@"` before `source test.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

as @pynexj said, "when you source easyoptions.sh it will parse all the command line options "
so you need following steps:

1.you need to check arguments in main process:

1.1 if the 1st argument is --help(1st argument means $1,not $0 "file name"),then show main help,

1.2 if the 1st argument is --test, loads test.sh and pass other arguments to child.

2. if the child process get argument --help, it show child's help.

here is an simple example, passing main.sh's argument to child(proc.sh).

main.sh:

```
echo "main:"
echo $1
echo $2
source ./proc.sh $2
```

proc.sh:

```
echo "proc:"
echo $1
```

when you run cmd

```
 ./main.sh test help
```

output：

```
main:
test
help
proc:
help
```

you can see,the second argument of main.sh is passed to child

Comment: i want to use https://github.com/renatosilva/easyoptions  but thanks after seeing your solution i got an idea to skip showing help when --help is not the first option. Which works but now issue is i cant re-source easyoptions second time, so i have to find a work around for that.